# geom_bar() giving an empty plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem with `geom_bar()` function from `ggplot2` package. I do not have an idea **why i do get an empty plot**! When i filter my dataset that `Variable == 'DDIFF_IK'`, the plot is not drawn, any other `Variable` is working well. I hope anyone can give me a tip what is wrong with the data or so.

Here is the sample data only for `Variable == 'DDIFF_IK'`:

```
data <- structure(list(Value_y = c(-0.189999999999998, -0.179999999999993, 
                                   -0.170000000000002, -0.159999999999997, -0.150000000000006, -0.149999999999991, 
                                   -0.140000000000001, -0.129999999999995, -0.120000000000005, -0.109999999999999, 
                                   -0.0999999999999943, -0.0900000000000034, -0.0799999999999983, 
                                   -0.0699999999999932, -0.0600000000000023, -0.0499999999999972, 
                                   -0.039999999999992, -0.0300000000000011, -0.019999999999996, 
                                   -0.0100000000000051, 0.0100000000000051, 0.019999999999996, 0.0300000000000011, 
                                   0.0400000000000063, 0.0499999999999972, 0.0600000000000023, 0.0700000000000074, 
                                   0.0799999999999983, 0.0900000000000034, 0.100000000000009, 0.109999999999999, 
                                   0.120000000000005, 0.129999999999995, 0.140000000000001, 0.150000000000006, 
                                   0.159999999999997), Variables = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "WW_DD_IK", class = "factor"), 
                       n = c(1L, 1L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 6L, 21L, 29L, 38L, 25L, 15L, 
                             11L, 19L, 15L, 28L, 22L, 19L, 13L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 
                             6L, 2L, 12L, 13L, 21L, 23L, 28L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 5L, 1L), 
                       prop = c(0.00210084033613445, 0.00210084033613445, 0.0105042016806723, 
                                0.023109243697479, 0.0273109243697479, 0.0126050420168067, 
                                0.0441176470588235, 0.0609243697478992, 0.0798319327731092, 
                                0.0525210084033613, 0.0315126050420168, 0.023109243697479, 
                                0.0399159663865546, 0.0315126050420168, 0.0588235294117647, 
                                0.046218487394958, 0.0399159663865546, 0.0273109243697479, 
                                0.00630252100840336, 0.00840336134453781, 0.00420168067226891, 
                                0.0147058823529412, 0.0189075630252101, 0.0126050420168067, 
                                0.0126050420168067, 0.00420168067226891, 0.0252100840336134, 
                                0.0273109243697479, 0.0441176470588235, 0.0483193277310924, 
                                0.0588235294117647, 0.0273109243697479, 0.0315126050420168, 
                                0.0294117647058824, 0.0105042016806723, 0.00210084033613445
                       )), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Value_y", "Variables", 
                                                            "n", "prop"), row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

and `ggplot()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Value_y, y=prop, fill=Variables)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 10)) + ylab("n / sum(n)") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold"),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=15), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=15), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=18, face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=18, face="bold"),
        legend.position="bottom", legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=14))
```

Thanks in advance!

**[Addition]**

Here is sample dataset with other `Variable`:

```
data2 <- structure(list(Value_y = c(-0.4, -0.39, -0.38, -0.37, -0.36, 
                                    -0.35, -0.34, -0.33), Variables = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "WW_DD_IK", class = "factor"), n = c(3L, 
                                                                                                                                                 11L, 32L, 47L, 22L, 15L, 14L, 3L), prop = c(0.0204081632653061, 
                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0748299319727891, 0.217687074829932, 0.319727891156463, 0.149659863945578, 
                                                                                                                                                                                             0.102040816326531, 0.0952380952380952, 0.0204081632653061)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("Value_y", "Variables", "n", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "prop"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

**above code to create plot is working...how come?**

**[Addition 2]**

Just to prove that the answer:

*If you use data=data[1:5,] you'll get a drawn plot. If you take a larger subset it simply can't be drawn properly*

is invalid in my case here is the sample of the bigger dataset (`data3`), which is working well and `ggplot()` is drawn...

```
data3 <- structure(list(Value_y = c(-0.19, -0.17, -0.14, -0.12, -0.11, 
                                    -0.1, -0.09, -0.08, -0.07, -0.06, -0.05, -0.04, -0.03, -0.02, 
                                    -0.01, 0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.180000000000007, 0.189999999999998, 
                                    0.200000000000003, 0.210000000000008, 0.219999999999999, 0.230000000000004, 
                                    0.239999999999995, 0.25, 0.260000000000005, 0.269999999999996, 
                                    0.280000000000001, 0.290000000000006, 0.299999999999997, 0.310000000000002, 
                                    0.320000000000007, 0.329999999999998, 0.340000000000003, 0.350000000000009, 
                                    0.359999999999999, 0.409999999999997, 0.420000000000002, 0.430000000000007, 
                                    0.439999999999998, 0.450000000000003, 0.460000000000008, 0.469999999999999, 
                                    0.480000000000004, 0.489999999999995, 0.5, 0.510000000000005, 
                                    0.519999999999996, 0.530000000000001), Variables = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                   1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                   2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("DD_ABM", "DDIFF_AK"), class = "factor"), 
                        n = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 38L, 40L, 57L, 
                              48L, 46L, 32L, 49L, 36L, 25L, 15L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 22L, 
                              10L, 21L, 36L, 36L, 42L, 37L, 25L, 17L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 11L, 
                              12L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 16L, 9L, 19L, 24L, 22L, 18L, 14L, 13L, 
                              20L, 7L, 2L), prop = c(0.00210084033613445, 0.00630252100840336, 
                                                     0.00210084033613445, 0.00840336134453781, 0.0315126050420168, 
                                                     0.0378151260504202, 0.0399159663865546, 0.0441176470588235, 
                                                     0.0798319327731092, 0.0840336134453782, 0.119747899159664, 
                                                     0.100840336134454, 0.0966386554621849, 0.0672268907563025, 
                                                     0.102941176470588, 0.0756302521008403, 0.0525210084033613, 
                                                     0.0315126050420168, 0.0147058823529412, 0.00210084033613445, 
                                                     0.00210084033613445, 0.00840336134453781, 0.0189075630252101, 
                                                     0.046218487394958, 0.0210084033613445, 0.0441176470588235, 
                                                     0.0756302521008403, 0.0756302521008403, 0.0882352941176471, 
                                                     0.0777310924369748, 0.0525210084033613, 0.0357142857142857, 
                                                     0.0126050420168067, 0.0105042016806723, 0.00840336134453781, 
                                                     0.023109243697479, 0.0252100840336134, 0.00420168067226891, 
                                                     0.00210084033613445, 0.00210084033613445, 0.0210084033613445, 
                                                     0.0336134453781513, 0.0189075630252101, 0.0399159663865546, 
                                                     0.0504201680672269, 0.046218487394958, 0.0378151260504202, 
                                                     0.0294117647058824, 0.0273109243697479, 0.0420168067226891, 
                                                     0.0147058823529412, 0.00420168067226891)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Value_y", 
                                                                                                                                 "Variables", "n", "prop"), row.names = c(NA, -52L))
```

Comment: If you're using `geom_bar` you will want your x_axis discrete rather than continuous.

Comment: You have to use `Value_y` as `factor()` in `aes`: `aes(x=factor(Value_y), y=prop, fill=Variables)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have not thought about that... however it wonders me why the data2 (in **Addition**) is working fine with continuous axis (its actually another sample of my data)...any ideas?

Comment: If you use `data=data[1:5,]` you'll get a drawn plot. If you take a larger subset it simply can't be drawn properly.

Comment: Well Your point @Haboryme  is invalid, have a look at **Addition 2** in my question, bigger dataset `data3`, and still the plot is drawn..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the size, as you showed, but the fact that in data there is `data$Value_y[6]` and `data$Value_y[5]` are both -0.15. This leads to overlapping.
Curiously `data$Value_y[6]==data$Value_y[5]` returns `FALSE` so I didn't catch it when comparing `length(unique(data$Value_y)` with `nrow(data)`.
But if you do remove either one with `data=data[-6,]` or `data=data[-5,]`, it will draw the plot.

Comment: I could not actually find the solution to it, and here it is! Thanks a lot!