# geom_bar() draws lines instead of bars

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geom-bar, stacked-chart

I have the following data:

```
d <- data.frame(id = rep(2,6), type = c(letters[1:6]), abund = c(27.3,2.7,2.3,2.1,1.2,0.3)) 

  id type abund
1  2    a  27.3
2  2    b   2.7
3  2    c   2.3
4  2    d   2.1
5  2    e   1.2
6  2    f   0.3
```

I want to **create a stacked barplot in `ggplot`**, but when I try it doesn't work correctly:

```
 library(ggplot2)

 ggplot(data = d, aes(x = abund, y = factor(id), fill = factor(type))) +
    theme_bw() + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

What I get (LEFT) and [conceptually*] what I want (RIGHT):

[image] [image]

I've tried moving around aesthetics and playing with factors, but nothing has worked. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41998081/4581200) seemed most similar to mine after an extensive search, but my problem is different.

**What do I do??**

---

*I say conceptually, because I drew this in ms paint. I want it to look like a typical `ggplot` stacked barchart.

Note: my actual desired end result is to have stacked barplots for multiple `id` groups (i.e., so I have `id = rep(2:6, each = 6)` using my example)

Comment: ggplot draws vertical bar charts by default. To make them horizontal, use `coord_flip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what your are looking for. We can flip the x and y axis using `coord_flip`.

```
d <- data.frame(id = rep(2,6), type = c(letters[1:6]), abund = c(27.3,2.7,2.3,2.1,1.2,0.3),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = d, aes(x = factor(id), y = abund, fill = factor(type))) +
  # geom_bar(stat='identity') will also work
  geom_col() +
  # Flip the x and y axis
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Another idea is to use `geom_rect`, but this requires the creation of `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, and `ymax`. Therefore, extra work is needed for the original data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

d2 <- d %>% 
  mutate(ymin = 0) %>%
  mutate(xmin = lead(abund), xmin = ifelse(is.na(xmin), 0, xmin)) 

ggplot(data = d2, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = abund, ymin = ymin, ymax = id, 
                      fill = factor(type))) +
  geom_rect() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: what in the ???....  could you add an explanation of why I need to do this please?

Comment: @theforestecologist I have added some brief explanation. You can try to comment out the `coord_flip` line to see the resulting outcome of this function.

Comment: @theforestecologist Added another option with `geom_rect`, although, extrat work is needed for this.

Comment: thanks, @www I appreciate the help on this! I swear, you can learn the intricacies of `ggplot` for a lifetime!